# Joining elements in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to join the 2nd and 3rd elements into one on the array i.e: [567, "O/S", '1,111']

Possible strings: 567/O/S/1,111 / 5/O/S/1,111 (The first element in the array could be up to 4 digits long)

I've got this working below but its not a very eloquent solution, is there a better way to do this? Possibly an es6 array function?

```
var array = '567/O/S/1,111'.split('/')

if(array.length > 3) {
  var text1 = array[1];
  var text2 = array[2];
  var joinedText = `${text1}/${text2}`;

  array.splice(1,2);
  array.splice(1, 0, joinedText);
}

console.log(array) //[567, "O/S", '1,111']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to either match a letter, followed by a slash and another letter, or anything but a slash:

```js
console.log(
  '567/O/S/1,111'.match(/[a-z]\/[a-z]|[^/]+/gi),
);
console.log(
  '5/O/S/1,111'.match(/[a-z]\/[a-z]|[^/]+/gi),
);
```

- `[a-z]\/[a-z]` - a letter, followed by a slash, followed by another letter
- `[^/]+` - one or more non-slash characters

Comment: This don't work in case there would be 3 chunks after split. `567/O/1,111`. OP has `if(array.length > 3)` in his code

Comment: This is really good thankyou! I should have mentioned the first element in the array could be between 1-4 digits long which the regex expression above fails on it produces ["5/O", "S/1", ",111" ]

Comment: @NoDachi See edit, I guess you need `[a-z]` instead of `\w`